# Test for median difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, median

Given samples of two distributions I am looking for a test for median difference (I.e. reject null in favor of evidence that medians are different.) I do not want to assume anything about both distributions. Is there any standard test for this situation?

I know Mood's median test, but I believe it assumes that the distributions are  shifted. $F_2(t) = F_1(t-a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I back this claim with these sources:

Buthmann, A. (2017). "[Understanding the Uses for Mood’s Median Test](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/hypothesis-testing/understanding-uses-moods-median-test/)". *I Six Sigma* blog post.

Taylor, A. D. (2012). "[Mood’s Median Test](https://web.archive.org/web/20120907070156/http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Etaylor/z631/moods.pdf)". Handout (PDF link via Wayback Machine). 2 pages.

Glen, S. (2016). "[Mood’s Median Test: Definition, Run the Test and Interpret Results](https://www.statisticshowto.com/moods-median-test/)". *Statistics How To: Elementary statistics for the rest of us* blog post.

Comment: Notice to possible answers: [Wilcoxon rank sum test (Mann-Whitney test) does not test for differences in medians](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html)!

Comment: +1 @Firebug is almost correct: the ran sum test only tests for median difference under stringent additional assumptions (which violates the OP's stated desiderata).

Comment: @Alexis  it is a test of medians when the distribution is symmetric, in which case it is also a test of means.

Comment: @AdamO It is a test of medians when both distributions have the same shape (symmetric or not), *and* when both distributions have the same variance... that is when it is simply a test of location shift. (And yes, then it happens to also be a test *for* mean difference.)

Comment: @Alexis down the rabbit hole. I just remembered reading that on R docs, so I thought about posting it haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could consider a permutation test.

```
median.test <- function(x,y, NREPS=1e4) {
  z <- c(x,y)
  i <- rep.int(0:1, c(length(x), length(y)))
  v <- diff(tapply(z,i,median))
  v.rep <- replicate(NREPS, {
    diff(tapply(z,sample(i),median))
  })
  v.rep <- c(v, v.rep)
  pmin(mean(v < v.rep), mean(v>v.rep))*2
}

set.seed(123)
n1 <- 100
n2 <- 200
## the two samples
x <- rnorm(n1, mean=1)
y <- rexp(n2, rate=1)
median.test(x,y)
```

[image]

Gives a 2 sided p-value of 0.1112 which is a testament to how inefficient a median test can be when we don't appeal to any distributional tendency.

If we used MLE, the 95% CI for the median for the normal can just be taken from the mean since the mean is the median in a normal distribution, so that's 1.00 to 1.18. The 95% CI for the median for the exponential can be framed as $\log(2)/\bar{X}$, which by the delta method is 0.63 to 0.80. Therefore the Wald test is statistically significant at the 0.05 level but the median test is not.

Comment: A warning: "The situation is even worse when basing a test on a difference in sample medians, in the sense that regardless of sample sizes, the asymptotic rejection probability of the permutation test will be α under very stringent conditions, which essentially means only in the case where the underlying distributions are the same." from https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1366138199. A better solution according to these authors would be to use a studendized version of the test statistic.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your outcome is ordinal or interval-valued, you can use the nonparametric `median` test with k=2. Here's a description from [Stata's implementation](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rranksum.pdf) of it:

> The median test examines whether it is likely that two or more samples
>   came from populations with the same median. The null hypothesis is
>   that the samples were drawn from populations with the same median. The
>   alternative hypothesis is that at least one sample was drawn from a
>   population with a different median. The test should be used only with
>   ordinal or interval data. Assume that there are score values for k
>   independent samples to be compared. The median test is performed by
>   first computing the median score for all observations combined,
>   regardless of the sample group. Each score is compared with this
>   computed grand median and is classified as being above the grand
>   median, below the grand median, or equal to the grand median.
>   Observations with scores equal to the grand median can be dropped,
>   added to the “above” group, added to the “below” group, or split
>   between the two groups. Once all observations are classified, the data
>   are cast into a 2xk contingency table, and a Pearson’s chi-squared
>   test or Fisher’s exact test is performed.

Comment: I belive this is Mood's median test. Are you sure that it does not assume that distribution are shifted?

Comment: @Manuel I am not familiar with Mood's median test, but it does seem very similar to what I proposed. However, the shift assumption does not appear among the others in the help file I linked, and it is not clear to me where it would be necessary here. It's possible that I am missing something, but perhaps you can add why you believe that it is needed?

Comment: I added to the question some links where they say that shifted distribution is necessary.