# Statistical Tests Comparing Median Wages

Tags: r, median

I am trying to find a statistical test that will compare the medians of two columns. When I try have searched around I have found the wilcox.test function in R, however, I have read mixed interpretations on whether this is for the median or the mean. Could someone confirm whether or not this would be appropriate to compare median wages over time? If not, what tests would you recommend?

Comment: The Wilcoxon test is a test of medians only when the distributions are symmetric, in which case it is also a test of means (most cases). Wages are often skewed. Why not log transform them, and then perform a t-test?

Comment: you could apply a permutation test for the difference or ratio of medians.

Comment: @AdamO - you forgot your answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327168/test-for-median-difference, which is a "better" duplicate!